# How to handle JWT token on the client site in Node.js application?

Tags: node.js, token, jwt

I am implementing JWT tokens for authentication.

I am not using any client-site framework like Angular or React. It is just EJS.

Step 1. I have an API developed that on successful login returns the token as shown on the picture below(I am using Postman for testing API):

[API response with JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfigr.png)

Step 2. I am then accessing the restricted route and passing along the Authorization header with token value, by inputing it manually in the Postman and it works just fine.

My question is WHERE and HOW do I save the returned token from the step 1 on the client, so that it is sent in the header on step 2.

I am novice to web-development and following the tutorials, but all the tutorials I found about implementing the JWT token are written for Angular or React when it comes to the client site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi roman. Could you update your question with the client-side code where you handle:
1. User Sign-in
2. User authentication (for pages that require authentication to access content).

Generally, however, you will want to use `localStorage`, which has a `setItem` method to store data locally (in this case, the token), and a `getItem` method to retrieve that data. Then it's only a matter of using the token properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First** you must create the token with JWT :

```
const token=jwt.sign({
                userId: user._id
                },config.secret, {expiresIn: '24h'});
                res.json({success:true,message:'Success', token:token, user: {username:user.username}});
```

**Then** in your front youcan save it into the [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

This will generate a unique key that you can implement in your header

**After that** in your routes when you want to check if there's a JWT in the header just make :

```
router.use((req,res,next)=>{
        const token=req.headers['authorization'];
        if(!token){
            res.json({success:false, message:"No token provided"});
        }
        else{
            jwt.verify(token, config.secret, (err,decoded)=>{
                if(err){
                    res.json({success:false,message:"Token invalid: " + err});
                }
                else{
                    req.decoded=decoded;
                    next();
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

This is a middleware that will check if there's a JWT key in "authorization" header

Note that every route coming after this one are going to run this middleware.

[Here](https://jwt.io/introduction/) You 'll find every details about JSON Web Tokens

**EDIT**

Here's how you could do with an AJAX request:

```
$("submit").click(function(){

    $.ajax({
       url : 'api/login,',
       type : 'POST',
       data : {login: $('#login').val(),password:$('#password').val()}
       dataType : 'JSON',
       success : function(data, statut){
           localStorage.setItem('token',data.token) // assuming you send a json token
       },

       error : function(resultat, statut, erreur){
         // whatever code you want
       },

       complete : function(resultat, statut){

       }

    });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Azoulay. As I mentioned in my post, I already implemented the controller, routes, etc which are handling the auth logic. The task is to save and provide the token on the client site.

Comment: To implement the jwt token in your client side you must use the local storage as I mentionned. You grab the data coming from the back then attribute this to the local storage using localStorage.setItem('token', data);
You should look at the link I've posted about local storage. Then if that answer helped you, can you please upvote and set it as resolved ? thanks

Comment: Hi Azoulay, unfortunately, it does not quite answer my question. I know the theory, but I don't know exactly how to implement it. I have a http://localhost:3000/api/login page, when I input my password and username and submit a form, controller is passing the data to API endpoint, which returns the json {"token":"blabla"}. How do I retrieve this data to save it then to the local storage?

Comment: @roman_js To retrieve this data you can make an AJAX Request.On submit, you call your API passing the submit data to your server, and as your Postman showed, it should response the token data on success. After that you just have to bind the token value with the local storage.

Comment: I forgot about the data sent, look at the edit again. Did it work for you ?

Comment: nope :( I can't seem to make a proper AJAX request to the API the request does not even appear in the log, so it might not even reach the end-point.

Answer (score 0):

Have an object where you store the token, if you want to keep the token after the user leaves so that he will remain connected as long as the token is valid, you can save it in the localStorage.

And when doing AJAX requests on client side, retrieve the token from your object of from localStorage and set the token in the Authorization header.