Authorization missing or empty after setting Headers
I've been trying to add set the authorization in my headers after a user logs in, but no matter what I've tried, the authorization field is either empty or missing.
If I log in from my application on the web and log what I get like this:
console.log("AccessTokenHere"); // I get the correct token
console.log("Logged in!");
res.header('Authorization', "Bearer " + accessToken);
console.log(req.headers);

This is what I get back:
{host: 'localhost:5001', connection: 'keep-alive', content-length: '48', cache-control: 'max-age=0', sec-ch-ua: '"Google Chrome";v="125", "Chromium";v="125", "Not.A/Brand";v="24"', …}
accept:'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7'
accept-encoding:'gzip, deflate, br, zstd'
accept-language:'en-CA,en;q=0.9,fr-CA;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6'
cache-control:'max-age=0'
connection:'keep-alive'
...

Authorization is nowhere to be seen.
Doing this on thunderClient though, I get an additional authorization:'' line.
I'm sending a post request through my login function:
const express = require("express");
const appUser = express();
const User = require("../models/userModel");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const mustache = require('mustache');
const path = require("path");
var engine = require('consolidate');
const http = require('http');
appUser.use(express.json());

appUser.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
appUser.engine('html', engine.mustache);
appUser.set('view engine', 'html');
appUser.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const login = asyncHandler (async (req, res) => {
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.Password;
    console.log(`${email}, ${password}`)
    if (!email || !password){
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Email or password not provided");
    }
    const user = await User.findOne({email});
    if (user && (await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password))) {
        const accessToken = jwt.sign({
            user: {
                username: user.id,
                email: user.email,
                id: user.id
            },
        }, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        {expiresIn: "30m"});
        console.log("AccessTokenHere");
        console.log("Logged in!");
        res.header('Authorization', "Bearer " + accessToken);
        console.log(req.headers);
        res.redirect(302, "/home/user/userPAGE");
    }
    else {
        res.status(400);
        throw new Error("Email or Password is not valid");
    }

});

Which then is supposed to redirect to another page after verification that the token is good by this function:
const asyncHandler = require("express-async-handler");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

const validateToken = asyncHandler(async (req, res, next) => {
    let token;
    let authHeader = String(req.headers['authorization'] || '');
    console.log(req.headers);
    console.log("boop");
    if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        token = authHeader.split(" ")[1];
        console.log("hey");
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
            if (err) {
                res.status(400);
                throw new Error("User is not authorized");
            }
            req.decoded = decoded.user;
            next();
        });
        if (!token) {
            res.status(401);
            throw new Error("User is not authorized or token is missing");
        }
    }
    else {
        res.status(401);
        throw new Error("User is not authorized or token is missing");
    }
});

But we don't even get there.
I've tried to use res.setHeader also, but that didn't work and other posts with this similar issue didn't help.

The standard Authorization header is a request header, not a response header. You should be able to send and receive it in a response anyway, but it’s not clear to me whether you expect some client to automatically receive the header and forward it to the redirect target. If you do expect that, well, it won’t. That’s not a thing.

I thought that, through the backend, I could get the accessToken in the headers and verify that the user logged in. Can I not do that?

You can do that if the client sends it, which is something you have to implement on the client.

Put the token in the res.body (it's not common to send Authorization in the res.header), and the client will get it and send it with each request.

So, I found [this][1] [1]:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46379410/how-to-handle-jwt-token-on-the-client-site-in-node-js-application) post where the person uses local storage to store the token. I was wondering if that's a good way to go about it because [a comment][2][2]:(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358100/how-to-access-localstorage-in-node-js) on this post was saying that localstorage doesn't work on the browse. It worked when I tried it locally though, so I wanted to know more about that.


Headers from the previous response are NOT added to the new request
for the redirected location.

Citation:
Why is my header not being set on redirect?
A workaround shown below.
It uses query string to pass the token during redirect.
server.js
const express = require('express');
const url = require('url');
const app = express();

app.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect(
    url.format({
      pathname: '/home',
      query: {
        localtion: 'login',
        accesstoken: 'someaccesstoken',
      },
    })
  );
});

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
  let accesstoken;
  if (req.query.localtion == 'login') {
    accesstoken = req.query.accesstoken;
  }

  console.log(`Redirected with this token ${accesstoken}`);
  res.send(`Redirected with this token ${accesstoken}`);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('L@3000'));

Testing the server:
Request URL : http://localhost:3000/login
Response at the server console : Redirected with this token someaccesstoken


Is using a query better practice than using local storage? Since I found a way for storing the token in the local storage.

Hi, Have your found the answer below useful ? @Deltag0ny

Sorry for the delay, hope you have got your solution in place.
However, I am answering to your question or the latest comment. As you know, query parameters are transferred from a client to a
server in a request. This is all about it.
Now let us start discussing cookies first.
Cookies have the built-in transferability as there is no need to include it exclusively in every request-response cycles. A cookie will automatically be included in every and in the entire request-response cycle.
It sends to the server and comes back from the server automatically.
Besides its automatic transferability, Cookies can store data as well.
It can be a persistent store or session store depending upon the configuration.
Therefore cookies are way beyond query parameters.
Moreover, the middleware softwares - express-session and cookie-session are built leveraging cookies. These middleware softwares provide great facilities to session management. A session object is created whenever a new request comes in, and a sessionID is assigned to it, and the response will take this information back to the client in the form of a cookie.
Every subsequent request to the same origin from the same client will always include the cookie. By this way, a server will know that a particular client session continues. With this, the stateless HTTP system becomes a stateful system.
Apart from that, a Session object can be protected, transported securely over HTTPS, can be set with automatic expiration time and it can provide many more finer controls as well.
These session objects can be persistent or session based. A persistent session can also be on the either sides as well. That is it can store not in the client but also in the backend through session store databases.
A localstorage on the other hand, comes only in the context of a client. It has no built-in role in server side or it does not take-part
in the whole request-response cycle as a cookie does. It has the obvious advantage to store more data than a cookie does. Therefore it is opted for storing larger data on the client side. However a localstore is still to be consistent across mobile platforms as the cookie system is.
Therefore a session middleware may a good choice in your case.
Citations:
Local Storage vs Cookies [closed]
Local Storage: How does it behave on mobile devices? Is it safe to use? What are the pitfalls? Need advice from devs who have used it [closed]
HTTP: When redirecting, does the server send response immediately?
Session Cookies vs Persistent Cookies: Understanding the Differences [Updated February 2024]
